# How can the 4-bit page number and 8-bit offset as well as the page table be used to a answer a question like, "how big is each page"? etc

Tags: scheduling

No more information required. I would just like to know how to use the information provided.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

4 bits page number + 8 bits offset = 12 address bits : A[11:0]

- A[7:0] selects an offset within a page
- A[11:8] selects the page
- 1792 = 7*256 : A=0111_00000000
- 2304 = 9*256 : A=1001_00000000
- 2814 =11*256 : A=1011_00000000
- 1024 = 4*256 : A=0100_00000000

What is the problem? You get 8 address bits within each page. So what is the page size?